# Get the containt of a div with jquery ( copy )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi sorry if i break some rules, and for my lower english !

I want to make an function who permit me to copy  some value like a Crtl + V !

but right know the result when i try to just alert the target value is "undefined" !

EDIT /// the right code is CODE :

```js
/*/// Fonction pour copier la valeur d'un champ */
$("i.copy").click(function(){
 alert($(this).parent().text());
});
```

```html
 
<p>
   <label>ID :</label><span>00010023 <i class="bt_action fa fa-clone copy" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</p>
```

all i want it's click on the i tag to get the span value ! 
thanks by advance , and so sorry again !

Comment: you did not give the parent any value, you gave it content. You could try to get what you want using `text()` instead of `val()`

Comment: Yes , i have make an edit , i have'nt verify the code before posting , thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.text()` and not `.attr("value")`

You span contain text and not a value.

```
$("i.copy").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text());
});
```

**demo**

```js
$("i.copy").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label>ID :</label><span>00010023 <i class="bt_action fa fa-clone copy" aria-hidden="true">trigger</i></span>
</p>
```

Comment: @Bharadwaj check now

Comment: thanks i have make an edit , it's exactly with .text() ! i have have just add .attr() , to make some test and forget to remove before posting

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 it's just the first part , show the value in a alert , for ctrl + c & ctrl + v , you may use the Document.execCommand() !